# Why I can't access the NPM modules for the aboutus.html page of my website?

Tags: npm

The NPM modules needed for my aboutus.html page cannot be found and I get a 404 error. Everything works perfectly for index.html though.

I looked into NPM server and the parsed path seems to be wrong:

```
19.01.20 22:33:07 304 GET /index.html
19.01.20 22:33:07 404 GET /aboutus.html/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

This is from the Chrome inspector:

`http://localhost:3000/aboutus.html/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

This is the path that I have in my code:

 `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">`

The aboutus.html page is located in the root of my folder so what I don't understand is why NPM is adding aboutus.html/ in front of my path. This doesn't happen for the index.html.

I already tried adding / and ../ in front of my paths but to no success.

Please bear with me since this is my first question here and I am also new to the web development field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was in linking the wrong way from the *index.html* page to the *aboutus.html* page.

This is the way it was linked before:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html/">About</a>
```

This is what I changed the line to:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About</a>
```

I hope this will help for people who will encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `/` in front of your paths. By default, the path is resolved relative, which in this case is after your `*.html` file. A `/` causes the path to be resolved absolutely to your server root.
On index.html, the URL is usually entered as `.../`, not `.../index.html`, which would have the same behavior.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/...">
```